# How to print double backslash?

Tags: characters

Is there an easy way to print "\\" in a Latex document? I tried using `\\\` and it threw an error.

Comment: In what context do you need it?

Comment: It's easy in verbatim: `\verb+\\+`  Of course, the appearance depends on the style you want, as @egreg has asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To print a "\", use `\backslash` in math mode and `\textbackslash` in text mode. To print "\\", use the command twice.